# Matching non multiline regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following file contents and I'm trying to match a reg explained below:

```
-- file.txt (doesn't match single/in-line text) -- 
test On blah more blah wrote:
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
---------------
```

If I read the file contents from above to a String and try to match the "On...wrote:" part I cannot get a match:

```
    // String text = <file contents from above>
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(On\\s(.+)wrote:)$");
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Never gets HERE???");
       // TODO: Strip out all characters after the match and any \s or \n before
    }
```

Essentially i want to the following output:

```
-- file2.txt -- 
test    
---------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you get the result you want:

```
        String text = "test On blah more blah wrote:\n" 
                + "blah blah blah\nblah blah\nblah\n";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\s*On\\s(.+)wrote:$", 
                Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            pw.println(m.group(1));
        }
        pw.close();
        System.out.println(sw);
```

Pattern.MULTILINE javadoc: *In multiline mode the expressions ^ and $ match just after or just before, respectively, a line terminator* ... I also added the (.*?) which matches everything before the first "On".

Comment: cool, thanks for the reply.  this is what I'm definitely looking for...now that I get a match, how can I replace everything but "test" in this case?  I have tried text = m.replaceAll("" ) but that replaces everything.

Comment: If you want to keep "test" (and the other non-matching lines) then use `m.replaceAll("$1")`. `$1` gets expanded to the first matching group.

Comment: thanks, so if I just want to keep test should I just use what is returned per m.group(1) or is there a way I can incorporate replaceAll("<regex here">)?

Comment: By using `Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\s*On\\s(.+)wrote:$.*", Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL)` you can get rid of all lines following test if you want that. `Pattern.DOTALL` makes dots also match line breaks, so the `.*` at the end of the pattern matches everything right to the very end of the text.

Comment: awesome! this was very, very helpful. everything worked beautifully. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

since the pattern you are looking for doesn't start the line, remove the `^`. This matches the beginning of a line, but your the line you are looking for starts with the word "test".

However if you want to capture the "test", then insert `(\\w+)\\s` after the `^` to form  `^(\\w+)\\s(On\\s(.+)wrote:)$`